# Bootstrap 3 modal with scrollable body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap modal, the default behavior is when the modal is shown, you can't scroll the body. I want something like this https://www.salesmachine.io/ (click watch video to show the modal) where I can scroll the body while the modal is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following to your CSS and this might help

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is the default Bootstrap rule.